# css flexbox: same height for all elements?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Using CSS and flexbox, I don't understand how to give the same height to divs "a" and "b". I need b to become taller so as to match a's height. In other words, the grey box should be as tall as the red box.

It was my understanding that it was enough to set `flex:1` to both a and b, in order for them to have same height. But it is not so.

I tried to set `flex-basis:0` to both "a" and "b", but the content is truncated. I cannot truncate a, I need b to be enlarged.

```css
#cont1{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}

#a{
    background-color:red;
    flex:1;
}

#b{
    background-color:grey;
    flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont1">
    <div id="a">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <h1>title</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="b">
        short text
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/wothbd5z/)

Comment: There is example, but using javascript :( ... https://jsfiddle.net/wothbd5z/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can *survive* without flex, positioning can do this.

```css
#cont1{
}

#a{
    background-color:red;
    position: relative;
}

#b{
    background-color:grey;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont1">
    <div id="a">
      <h1> title </h1>
      <h1> title </h1>
      <h1> title title title title title title title title title</h1>
      <div id="b">
        short text
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify a height for the flex container.

Try this:

```
#cont { 
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     height: 400px;
}
```

You need to create a defined space for the flex items to distribute.

---

**UPDATE** (based on comments)

> right... here's what I need to achieve: http://www.jsfiddle.net/s2b0v4ph (watch
>   on wide screen because there is a breakpoint)
>
> and here is the problem: if the box #2 becomes taller, the alignment
>   is broken between box #2 and box #5: http://www.jsfiddle.net/s2b0v4ph/1

The layout is working perfectly, as coded. The flex items of the primary flex container (`.flex-md`) are stretching the full-height of the container. No matter how much content you add to box #1 or box #2, the column containing boxes #5 and #6, will be equal height.

[image]

*All columns in the primary flex container (`<div class="row flex-md" id="row-quadrati">`) are equal height, regardless of content quantity. http://jsfiddle.net/s2b0v4ph/1/*

The reason that box #5 does not align with box #2 when content is added is that each of those boxes exists in a different [flex formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers). In other words, the boxes exist in different flex containers.

Specifically, boxes #1, #2 and #3 are flex items of `#quadr-col-1`, and boxes #4, #5 and #6 are flex items of `#quadr-col-2`. Both `#quadr-col-1` and `#quadr-col-2` are flex items of the primary flex container, doubling as (nested) flex containers, themselves.

Because these boxes exist in separate flex containers there is no reason for them to share equal height. If you want the flex equal height feature to apply, put them all in the same flex container.

Comment: thanks but this defeats the purpose of using flexbox. I don't know the height as it depends on the browser window width. when I shrink the window, the text wraps and the height of the container increases.

Comment: This does not defeat the purpose of flexbox. `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` work by distributing space available in the flex container. What's the height of the flex container? How can `flex` distribute space if it doesn't know how much space there is?

Comment: flex could simply give the container the _minimum_ height such that a and b have the same height...

Comment: Not sure I'm following you. Maybe you could provide more details in your question, or add before / after images.

Comment: right... here's what I need to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/s2b0v4ph/       (watch on wide screen because there is a breakpoint)

Comment: and here is the problem: if the box #2 becomes taller, the alignment is broken between box #2 and box #5: https://jsfiddle.net/s2b0v4ph/1/

Comment: Thanks, I understand your answer, but I don't see how I can "put them all in the same flex container". Note that on small screens, the box containing 4,5,6 must wrap on another line. on big screens, 5,6,2,3 must have same height.

Comment: Yes, that may take some fundamental restructuring of your code. I don't use bootstrap, which is why I didn't try  doing it myself; I'm not sure I can provide the most efficient solution. I'll take a look again tonight after work

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in javascript as follows, but I am still interested in a css solution:

```
function computeMaxHeight(els) {
    var ht = 0;
    els.forEach(function (el) {
        var elht = el.height();
        if (elht > ht) {
            ht = elht;
        }
    });
    return ht;
}

function setMinMeight(els) {
    var maxht = computeMaxHeight(els);
    //console.log("here resize. maxht = " + maxht);

    els.forEach(function (el) {
        el.css('min-height', maxht);
    });

}

$(document).ready(function () {

    var els = [$("#non-porre-limiti"), $("#we-love-pagi"), $("#vuoto"), $("#pagiletter"), $("#pagi-focus")];

    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        setMinMeight(els);

    });

    setMinMeight(els);

});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s2b0v4ph/3/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my JS solution to this problem, which selects the tallest of any number of elements and adjusts the height of the other elements accordingly:

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element-name');

if (elements) {
    let arr = [];

    let fixHeight = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
            let height = elements[i].offsetHeight;
            arr.push(height);

            var highest = Math.max(...arr);
        }

        elements.forEach((el) => {
            el.style.height = highest + 'px';
        });
    };

    fixHeight();

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        fixHeight();
    });
}
```

I would be also curious about a neater CSS solution to the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The trick is this part

```
.xyz {
  width: 70%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-flex: 9 0 0; 
  flex: 9 0 0; 
}
```

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/XmxmQE

Now these divs will have the same height, no matter the overall pages height.

Is this what you have looked for?

Comment: interesting, but I want the grey box as big as needed to match the height of the red box, but not more. In your code, height:100vh does the trick, but makes the boxes higher than necessary.