# How do I set the same height of two different divs in CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How do I set two different divs in their own child parent elements to the same size in CSS? The problem is similar to setting two different divs in the same element, but I'm not sure how to extend it do a lower child element.

I've created a jsfiddle for it that shows the problem. I would like the green section to expand to be just as large as the red section (automagically).

I am currently using a display flex system, but I'm open to using display table if you have an idea using that.

"box1" should be as large as whatever "box2" is (height wise).

https://jsfiddle.net/421hh08e/1/

```
<div class="outsideflex">
  <div class="leftbox">
    <div class="box1">Label 1</div>
    <div>Label 2</div>
    <div>Label 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightbox">
    <div class="box2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis imperdiet laoreet orci, vel vestibulum turpis gravida eget. Nam nibh enim, tristique sit amet lectus non, rhoncus tincidunt nibh. Etiam eu mi quis purus viverra mattis. Praesent malesuada, urna in vehicula tempor, lorem diam bibendum sapien, eget ornare elit diam nec ante. Proin et eros velit. Morbi congue leo et eros volutpat egestas. Proin laoreet varius luctus. Quisque quis tincidunt orci. Vestibulum lobortis congue porttitor.</div>
    <div>Value 2</div>
    <div>Value 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The example and "problem case" is that I need the text in one column to match the other. Think of it is a label on the left and value on the right. The data unfortunately doesn't provide me with good ids to match on so I have to rely on just listing out the arrays.

In short, I can't change the template much because each area is looped through separately.

This is NOT the same as the question posed [css flexbox: same height for all elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723411/css-flexbox-same-height-for-all-elements) because the elements are child elements within two entirely separate elements, not child elements of a single div.

Comment: Your example can allow this from your content demo https://jsfiddle.net/421hh08e/2/ but i'm not sure it would in any case https://jsfiddle.net/421hh08e/4/ . display:table/table-cell; will require to break each content side by side in a single row and as siblings . display:grid could be also an hint if every boxes sprayed in 2 cols would be siblings. Can you clarify example cases ?

Comment: That actually looks like it fits the example case. The problem was that a large amount of text in one side was not matching the other "column" and the alignment of text in each column is important. I should add that to the question

Comment: @Organiccat You may be better off grouping your items by row rather than column.

Comment: yes, example 2 shows it break. both contents side by side should be sibblings to easy do it via flex or table-cell. grid could also manage it most ways. Best would be to rethink HTML structure :) Sometimes content do really fit to an HTML table ..... ;)

Comment: Change structure to this https://jsfiddle.net/421hh08e/6/

Comment: Is it always the right box having the longest content?

Comment: another example structure based on flex : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpPpbv :)

Comment: This must be the simplest solution: https://jsfiddle.net/421hh08e/7/

Comment: I can't change the way the template is setup. I have two entirely separate lists I'm looping over, unless you have a different way of looping over two separate lists while using that layout.

Answer (score 0):

how are you?

My suggestion is to work with a grid system.
I made a quick example to explain better, I would like you to tell me what you think of this suggestion.

```css
.row {
 display: flex; /* equal height of the children */
}
.col {
 flex: 1; /* additionally, equal width */
}
.bg-primary {background-color: green;}
.bg-secondary {background-color: red;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col bg-primary">
  Label 1
 </div>
 <div class="col bg-secondary">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis imperdiet laoreet orci, vel vestibulum turpis gravida eget. Nam nibh enim, tristique sit amet lectus non, rhoncus tincidunt nibh. Etiam eu mi quis purus viverra mattis. Praesent malesuada, urna in vehicula tempor, lorem diam bibendum sapien, eget ornare elit diam nec ante. Proin et eros velit. Morbi congue leo et eros volutpat egestas. Proin laoreet varius luctus. Quisque quis tincidunt orci. Vestibulum lobortis congue porttitor.
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col">Label 2</div>
 <div class="col">Value 2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col">Label 3</div>
 <div class="col">Value 3</div>
</div>
```

[exemple grid system][1]

```
            [1]: http://codepen.io/CesarCEARA/pen/dvNvXP
```

http://codepen.io/CesarCEARA/pen/dvNvXP

Regards,

Cesar Barros

Comment: I would use a table/grid, but this structure won't work because I have to loop through two different data sets.

Comment: You should set a snippet with HTMl and CSS here to avoid being downvoted for a lazy trick :)

Comment: Thanks very much GCyrillus,

Now it should be correct.
I'm new to stackoverflow, I created the account to contribute to the community and help those who need it. I'm still learning how it works.